# Learning About Languages

Tags: programming-languages, learning, theory, grammar

I'm interested in learning more *about* programming languages.  In particular, I'd like to look at some of the new developments in programming languages (even the really obscure ones that only academics care about).  I need to learn to read grammar specifications, as well.  Where should I begin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A good place to start your studies in programming language design is with Van Roy and [Haridi's Concepts, Techniques, and Models of Computer Programming](http://www.info.ucl.ac.be/~pvr/book.html). For instance, [Programming Paradigms for Dummies: What Every Programmer Should Know](http://www.info.ucl.ac.be/~pvr/VanRoyChapter.pdf).

[Lambda the Ultimate](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/) is a forum dedicated to studying programming languages, so should prove a pretty good place to read about the cutting edge of the field of language design.

Comment: +1 for Lambda the Ultimate - IIRC they have a page of links to basic theory stuff

Comment: Lambda the Ultimate is excellent!

Answer (score 3):

If you are serious about learning in-depth stuff, I would recommend watching the [MIT OpenCourseWare](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-821-programming-languages-fall-2002/) class on the subject.

Course description:

> 6.821 teaches the principles of functional, imperative, and logic
>   programming languages. Topics covered
>   include: meta-circular interpreters,
>   semantics (operational and
>   denotational), type systems
>   (polymorphism, inference, and abstract
>   types), object oriented programming,
>   modules, and multiprocessing. The
>   course involves substantial
>   programming assignments and problem
>   sets as well as a significant amount
>   of reading. The course uses the
>   Scheme+ programming language for all
>   of its assignments.

Answer (score 2):

The [dragon book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book_%28computer_science%29) is a great practical intro.

It doesn't cover what makes a programming language suitable/usable for a particular task, and was written before most modern languages, but it does introduce the major sub-disciplines that lie between code and a running program.  Read it and you'll be well prepared to understand more recent developments in sub-fields like:

1. Notation: the notations used for grammars like [Backus-Naur form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form),
2. Grammar Theory: a bit on [Chomsky's hierarchy of grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#The_hierarchy) and getting used to thinking of a language as a set of strings with [associated semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_semantics).
3. [Lexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis): the distinction between lexers (operators over token stream) and grammars,
4. [Parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree): how grammars are converted to parse trees,
5. Inspecting: how to perform optimizations on parse trees, derive symbol tables, and the like
6. Pre-compiling: how to convert parse trees to a variety of intermediate forms (like [three-operand form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_address_code)) that have the structure of a real instruction set, but without the architecture-specific assumptions,
7. [Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization): converting programs into simpler/more-efficient but equivalent programs
8. Binary generation: how to convert those intermediate forms into actual instructions that can be run by a processor or virtual machine

---

The dragon book doesn't cover modern type systems, formal semantics, or other tools that assist in program correctness.  For a great introduction to type systems and formal reasoning, see ["Types And Programming Languages" by B. Pierce](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/).

---

Once you understand the role each of the various sub-fields play, you should start searching for papers titled "Survey of ... in programming languages" and "Recent developments in programming languages for ...".

Comment: +1 Dragon book is indeed a good book on compilers and their principle components.  As the book is quite old now, it will not lend to current developments, but a good grounding.  Just realised I first read that over 11 years ago, time flies!

Comment: would you mind explaining more on what it does and why do you recommend it as answering the question asked? ["Link-only answers"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info "what's this") are not quite welcome at Stack Exchange

Comment: @gnat, please see my rewrite.